# Is it possible to change a label by voice?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

I want to have a set of images/labels. Let's call them labelOne and labelTwo. When labelOne is present is it possible to change it to labelTwo using voice?

Example. As I say "one" the labelOne changes to labelTwo.

Is this possible with speech kit? If so, can I host some voice recognition on the app so it doesn't have to contact the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by using iSpeech its possible, but iSpeech is paid. The better option to do this via OpenEars

[Follow this official doc](http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can do that.But if you wanted to track just few keywords then don't go with API implementation it will be time consuming as well,Just use "Keyword Spotting".also you can use open source package like OpenEars which i had used in my project voice recognition logic and all.
check following ref which i made for my self as bookmark

1. http://appaloud.com/top-sdks-to-voice-enable-mobile-apps-quickly/
2. http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri
3. http://www.politepix.com/openears
4. http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial
5. Rejecto Plugin

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I use OpenEars (http://www.politepix.com/openears/) to do my voice recognition. It works offline and supports grammar based rules too.

Here is a video of it in action: http://youtu.be/idq7IRnrVq8